# How to make a synthesizable Instruction Memory in SystemVerilog?

Tags: system-verilog, processor, synthesis

I am designing a MIPS processor on SystemVerilog. The instruction memory is made like this:

```
   module instr_mem
#(
    parameter SIZE = 7 //64
)
(
    input logic rst_n, 
    input logic clk,
    
    input   logic [31:0] addr,
    output  logic [31:0] rd
);

logic [31:0] rom [0 : SIZE-1];

assign rd = rom[addr];

initial begin
    rom <= {
        32'h0,
        32'h2408000F, // a = F
        32'h240A0000, // res = 0

        32'h01485021, // (*) res = res + a
        32'h2508FFFF, // a = a - 1

        32'h1500FFFD, // if (a != 0) goto (*)
        32'hAC0A0ADD
    };
end

endmodule
```

But this code **doesn't synthesizes** as a 'black box'/separate module etc., the Top Module looks like: "*Core, Data Memory, < a big mess of something instead of Instuction Memory >*".
I tried to make IM combinational (`assign rom = {..}`), but synthesis goes the same way.

How can I make a synthesizable Instruction Memory? Btw, is there any guides to write surely synthesizable code?

Answer (score 0):

For Xilinx Vivado, the synthesis guide is Xilinx doc UG901.  Each vendor and tool version will be different.  Consult the synthesis tool vendor docs for guidance.  As an example, I found this version of UG901.
[https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2017_1/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf](http://%20https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2017_1/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf)   Chapter 4 has a section called 'ROM HDL Coding Techniques'.  This provides the guidance you requested.

The coding style shown in the image uses a case statement and will infer a ROM for a 4 bit selection variable 'addr'.
Put your own values on the RHS of the = assignment rather than the ones listed in the image.  You should assign 'rom' where the example assigned 'data'.  The variable 'data' shown in the image uses a packed dimension only (your example has a packed and unpacked); eliminate the unpacked dimension (the '[0 : SIZE-1]' part) from your deceleration of 'rom'.  Also, change the line 'assign rd = rom[addr];' to 'assign rd = rom;  Use default: rom = '0 to define all cases.  You can use always_comb rather than always @* as a more SystemVerilog approach.  Its better because always_comb always gets evaluated at t=0 in simulation, where always @* does not.

[image]

As an alternate approach for making a SystemVerilog ROM, use $readmh(), which reads a file into the memory variable 'rom' as shown in the SystemVerilog spec section 21.4 'Loading memory array data from a file'. [https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595][3]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595%5D%5B3%5D)
There is a nice tutorial on $readmh() here.
https://projectf.io/posts/initialize-memory-in-verilog/

This approach ( using a file & $readmh() ), may require a symlink at the project root pointing to the file read by $readmemh().  Define the 'rom' variable with both packed and unpacked dimensions when using this method.  This approach is prefered in the case where you have a lot of data to store in the ROM.  It would not be easy to maintain hundreds of thousands of lines in a case statement.

A general reference for SystemVerilog synthesis is:  "RTL Modeling with SystemVerilog for Simulation and Synthesis: Using SystemVerilog for ASIC and FPGA Design" by Stu Sutherland is very good for SystemVerilog (opinion) with emphasis on synthesis.